# CakePHP 3: Encrypt/decrypt password

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How can I show the decrypted user password in an edit form?

I am using `DefaultPasswordHasher` for `Hashing` passwords while registration of `users` using this:

```
protected function _setPassword($password) {
  return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

It works well and the password is encrypted...

But when I used `user table` in `view page` and `edit page` it shows the **encrypted** password. So how can I decrypt the password in the controller and when edit page it also decrypt and store in database in `CakePHP 3.x`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Simple answer is: You can't**

The whole point of hashing is that you cannot reverse engineer the password. So that when your database is hacked or leaked no harm can be done with the passwords.

Any website showing you your own password has a severe security problem and I would not use it.

There is also no point in showing the encrypted password. Editing a password is not needed, you just overwrite the old one (when they can still provide their old one ofc), and if one of your user forget their own password you should provide them with a recovery system using their email for example.

Comment: but when you need to update users profile using Cakephp3,you need to first shown users old password ..for that we must be write some function or code that decrypt stored password that is encrypted.. so my question is that how can we decrypt the password in controller in cakephp3??

Comment: again the simple answer: You can't. It is impossilble to decrypt a properly hashed password.

Comment: So how the recovery system works? How do they sent the original password to the user via email?

Comment: @Vito, Never! You either sent the user a new password on request or a link with a one time token to change the password themselves. I cannot stress enough that any system that sends you or shows you your own password in any way is broken and has big security issues.